# whats the correct way to define custom builds of vendor libraries in bower_components?

Tags: requirejs, gruntjs, amd, yeoman

I am using the yeoman webapp generator with requirejs and I have installed canjs using bower.

canjs has a dir structure like the following

```
app/bower_components/canjs/amd/can.js
app/bower_components/canjs/amd/can/control.js
app/bower_components/canjs/amd/can/control/route.js
etc..
```

Inside the can.js file is the following.

```
define(["can/util/library", "can/control/route", "can/model", "can/view/ejs", "can/route"], function(can) {
    return can;
});
```

All of the dependancy files (control.js, route.js) have their dependancies listed inside define() functions.

What I want to do is customise the canjs build and replace "can/view/ejs" with "can/view/mustache". I can get it to work by changing the reference to ejs within the can.js file but that means I'm editing a vendor file inside of bower_components dir.

I have tried to create a mycan.js build within my scripts dir which looks the same as the can.js file (except for the mustache dependency change) in bower_components and then I change the config to look like this.

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: '../bower_components/jquery/jquery',
        can: '../bower_components/canjs/amd/can',
        etc..
```

Then I require the mycan module in any of my files that need it.

This will work properly if I comment out the code inside bower_components/canjs/amd/can.js but if I don't comment the file out, it will require both builds (including the can/view/ejs file I didn't want).

In the require docs http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html under usage 1.1, it has an example of

```
•   www/
•   index.html
•   js/
•   app/
•   sub.js
•   lib/
•   jquery.js
•   canvas.js
•   app.js
```

and in app.js:

```
requirejs.config({
     //By default load any module IDs from js/lib
    baseUrl: 'js/lib',
    //except, if the module ID starts with "app",
    //load it from the js/app directory. paths
    //config is relative to the baseUrl, and
    //never includes a ".js" extension since
    //the paths config could be for a directory.
    paths: {
        app: '../app'
    }
});

// Start the main app logic.
requirejs(['jquery', 'canvas', 'app/sub'],
function   ($,        canvas,   sub) {
    //jQuery, canvas and the app/sub module are all
    //loaded and can be used here now.
});
```

Here they are using a path which is a directory, not a file. The sub module is getting found because it matches app/sub with the app in the paths config.

If I define my own version of can within the main.js file which contains the require.config then it seems to work but then when I go to build the app, it says

```
tim@machine:~/server/javascript/yoman:ruby-1.9.3: (master)$ grunt
Running "jshint:all" (jshint) task
Linting app/scripts/main.js ...ERROR
[L54:C1] W117: 'define' is not defined.
define('can', [

Warning: Task "jshint:all" failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.

Elapsed time
default     567ms
jshint:all  124ms
Total       691ms
```

Whats the correct way for me to make a custom build of vendor libraries within bower_components?

Here is my main.js. This version works but fails when linting.

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: '../bower_components/jquery/jquery',
        bootstrapAffix: '../bower_components/sass-bootstrap/js/affix',
        bootstrapAlert: '../bower_components/sass-bootstrap/js/alert',
        bootstrapButton: '../bower_components/sass-bootstrap/js/button',
        bootstrapCarousel: '../bower_components/sass-bootstrap/js/carousel',
        bootstrapCollapse: '../bower_components/sass-bootstrap/js/collapse',
        bootstrapDropdown: '../bower_components/sass-bootstrap/js/dropdown',
        bootstrapPopover: '../bower_components/sass-bootstrap/js/popover',
        bootstrapScrollspy: '../bower_components/sass-bootstrap/js/scrollspy',
        bootstrapTab: '../bower_components/sass-bootstrap/js/tab',
        bootstrapTooltip: '../bower_components/sass-bootstrap/js/tooltip',
        bootstrapTransition: '../bower_components/sass-bootstrap/js/transition',
        can: '../bower_components/canjs/amd/can'
    },
    shim: {
        bootstrapAffix: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        bootstrapAlert: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        bootstrapButton: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        bootstrapCarousel: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        bootstrapCollapse: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        bootstrapDropdown: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        bootstrapPopover: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        bootstrapScrollspy: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        bootstrapTab: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        bootstrapTooltip: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        bootstrapTransition: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
});

define('can', [
    'can/util/library',
    'can/control/route',
    'can/construct/proxy',
    'can/model',
    'can/view/mustache',
    'can/route'
], function(can) {
    'use strict';
    return can;
});


require(['app', 'jquery'], function (app, $) {
    'use strict';
    // use app here
    console.log(app);
    console.log('Running jQuery %s', $().jquery);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSHint is complaining because require is in an external file. All require's functions are defined before your script loads, but because they're not *inside* the script JSHint thinks they're custom code which you forgot to define. This is an easy fix; add a *predef* config so that `define`, `require` are already passed to JSHint before it starts linting your files.

```
  jshint: {
     options: {
        // all of your other options...
        predef: ['define', 'require']
     },
     files : ['app/scripts/main.js']
  },
```